# predictions in regression

Tags: regression, prediction

I have simple linear model - assume height and weight in humans are linearly related.

```
    height <- 62:76
    weight <- c(134, 136, 138, 140, 142, 145,  148, 151, 154,
              157, 160, 164,    168, 172, 176)
    mod1 <- lm(weight ~ height)
    mod1

    Call:
    lm(formula = weight ~ height)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       height  
     -54.67         3.00
```

I would like to make some predictions. What would be weight when height is 68.5.

```
   newdata = data.frame(height=68.5)    
    predict(mod1, newdata)
           1 
    150.8333
```

I want to test (with test static) whether average weight is less than 155 when the height is 68.5. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the hypothesis is:

NULL H0: Weight = 155, when height = 68.5

Alternate Ha: Weight < 155, when height = 68.5

```
    se <- predict(mod1, newdata, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
    ym <- predict(mod1, newdata, se.fit = TRUE)$fit
```

Calculate t statistics to test the above hypothesis:

```
ts <- (ym - 155)/ se
```

pvalue for 14 df

```
pt(ts, 14)
4.607475e-08
```

We reject null hypothesis.